# Is there a way to make my Delphi code neater,more easy to read ect

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I would like to take my mess of 'if' and 'for' loops and make them look professional and neat. Without having to manually tab the nested loops.
Any ideas?

Comment: [Codereview stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be better for this type of question rather than StackOverflow. Also when asking the question, add the code relating to the question so that people can help you.

Comment: Per se not a question for SO. Personally I use cnpack (a great, free plugin which has "indent nicely" function of code. To identify function headers, I use figlet banner text with comments, and line describing the procedure / function.

Comment: Thank you so much, i really do appreciate it

Comment: Right-click the code view and select "Format code" or press Ctrl-D. You can modify the formatting settings in "Options-Language-Formatter-Delphi..."

Comment: you are a legend

Comment: @Thamognya Please see [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This is a perfectly good place to ask about how to do a specific task with a program whether it is finalized or not. Codereview is more for review of algorithms in finalized programs or functions with respect to their programming style, not how to use the programming tool to "beautify" the source. The Delphi IDE (as most other IDE's) include functionality to standardize formatting of code.

Comment: @MyICO, please see my previous comment.

Answer (score 4):

Right-click the code view and select "Format code" or press Ctrl-D.

You can modify the formatting settings in "Options-Language-Formatter-Delphi..."